# Conditional JOINs based on column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to conditionally join one master event table to three others depending on an event type. The select statement works fine, and returns the result set I'd expect, but when I add the JOIN statements, I get an error saying the column aliases were not found:

```
SELECT 
event.type as type,
IF(type = 'birthday', event.target_id, NULL) as birthday_id,
IF(type = 'graduation', event.target_id, NULL) as graduation_id,
IF(type = 'wedding', event.target_id, NULL) as wedding_id
FROM event
LEFT OUTER JOIN birthday ON birthday_id = birthday.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN graduation ON graduation_id = graduation.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN wedding ON wedding_id = wedding.id
```

Gets this error:

> Unknown column 'birthday_id' in 'on clause'

---

**UPDATE:** Ok Sebas just indicated you can't join on calculation results, in which case my approach is off. So what is the correct approach for doing something like this?

Comment: Would you mind adding aliases everywhere for us to have a better overview of the query please?

Comment: Hmm, you can't join with calculation results, I'm going to post an answer.

Comment: answer posted! Note that I think you actually would like to show the event type and corresponding event id instead of NULL NULL weddingID (for example). This would also be possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    event.type as type,
    IF(type = 'birthday', birthday.id, NULL) as birthday_id,
    IF(type = 'graduation', graduation.id, NULL) as graduation_id,
    IF(type = 'wedding', wedding.id, NULL) as wedding_id
FROM 
    event
        LEFT OUTER JOIN birthday b  ON event.target_id = b.id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN graduation g    ON b.id IS NULL AND event.target_id = g.id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN wedding w   ON b.id IS NULL AND g.id IS NULL AND event.target_id = w.id
```

should do the trick, give me feedback! 
rgds.

edit: See the IS NULL conditions. I didn't test it, I wonder if mysql would accept it! If yes, then almost only the necessary joins would be done...

Comment: Thanks Sebas- So this would actually join all three tables if they each had an id that matched the target id right? I guess it would work, but seems so inefficient..

Comment: Hmm makes me think of something, please have a look at the coming update

Comment: Don't know if that update would work, but i think the sql's getting too twisted ... this might be a job for sub-queries- anyway, thanks for sticking with it, appreciate the effort

Comment: you're welcome! I'm pretty sure we should reformulate the original need I think, because I think ther's a conceptual problem showing the event type and then the birthday, graduation plus wedding even though it is out of concern. rgds.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join all of the tables with the same field, event.target_id, and when you need to show some specific data, you can test the type before.

Example:

```
SELECT 
event.type as type,
IF(type = 'birthday', birthday.birthday_id, NULL) as birthday,
IF(type = 'graduation', graduation.graduation_id, NULL) as graduation,
IF(type = 'wedding', wedding.wedding_id, NULL) as wedding
FROM event
LEFT OUTER JOIN birthday ON birthday_id = event.target_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN graduation ON graduation_id = event.target_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN wedding ON wedding_id = event.target_id
```

Not testes, but hope this helps you elucidate your doubts.

Comment: Thanks J, same answer as Sebas, he beat you by a hair

Answer (score 0):

Sebas answer is correct but need not conditions to check IS NULL for each previous joins, you can use based column value to make it effective. I have tested this and its working.

```
SELECT 
    E.type AS type,
    IF(E.type = 'birthday', B.id, NULL) AS birthday_id,
    IF(E.type = 'graduation', G.id, NULL) AS graduation_id,
    IF(E.type = 'wedding', W.id, NULL) AS wedding_id
FROM event E 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN birthday B ON E.type = 'birthday' AND E.target_id = B.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN graduation G ON E.type = 'graduation' AND E.target_id = G.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN wedding W ON E.type = 'wedding' AND E.target_id = W.id
```